# Fundamental Group of the Sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, solution-verification

I have just started Algebraic Topology and have encountered the fundamental group of a sphere for the first time. The proof I am following is here:

[image: proof]

I think I understand everything, barring the sentence underlined. How would I prove this statement? What do the sets $U$ and $V$ look like?

Comment: Cut the sphere into half, $U$ and $V$ are probably meant to be these two "halves" essentially I think (with a bit of overlap). You see these two halves will be homeomorphic to the open disc

Comment: I see. How do you deal with the fact that $U$ and $V$ need to be open? The union of the open hemispheres is not equal to the sphere. I guess there is a natural enlarging of one of the hemispheres to an open set which is still homeomorphic to the open disc?

Comment: Ahhh, just as you gave this comment and I was starting to type an answer, @Troposphere explained. The two open hemispheres will have a bit of overlap

Comment: You could pick $q \in S^2 -\{p\}$, and then use $U=S^2-\{q\}$ and $V=S^2-\{p\}$. A 2-sphere minus a point is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$, by stereographic projection; and therefore is also homeomorphic to an open 2-disc.

Comment: Thanks, and I suppose the openess of the chosen sets follows from the fact that singletons are closed in any metric space?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They key is in what the underlined sentence does *not* say: It doesn't require that the sets $U$ and $V$ be *disjoint*. In fact they *have* to overlap, as hinted by the later reference to $U\cap V$.

You have considerable freedom to choose a pair of $U$ and $V$ that meets the description. For example, you could picture $p$ as the south pole of a globe and let $U$ consist of all points strictly south of 45° N, and $V$ consist of all points strictly north of 45° S.

Or, for a more "minimal" (in some sense) choice, let $V=S^2\setminus\{p\}$, then select $q$ to be an *arbitrary* point in $V$ (or pick the antipode of $p$ if you don't like making arbitrary choices) and let $U=S^2\setminus\{q\}$.

---

It's tempting to say let's pick $U$ to be $S^2\setminus\{q\}$ for some $q$ that $\alpha$ doesn't hit. Then you won't have to deal with $V$ at all and you can simply contract the curve by linear scaling in the standard map of the open disc, avoiding the need to break the curve into sub-intervals. Unfortunately, however, the existence of [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) means you can't be sure there's any such $q$ to pick.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Maybe an image let you understand the situation.

As you can see $U$ and $V$ are open sets and homeomorphic to disc.
They also cover the sfere and $P$ is not in $V$

Obviously this are not the only opens that verify the conditions.

If you want a more explicit example of $U$ and $V$ you can think on see the sfere like $\{(x,y,z)/x^2+y^2+z^2=1\}$[image]

And take $U=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{S}^2 /z>-\epsilon\}$
$V =\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{S}^2 /z<\epsilon\}$

With $\epsilon >0$